# Regex lookahead or lookbehind

Tags: c#, regex

I am learning how to use regex lookahead and lookbehind.

I want to extract json value from a text just like this

```
{"html":"\n\t\t\t\t<table class=\"table\">"}
```

I am using regex on C# like this

```
 Regex.Match(text, "\"html\":\"([^(?<!\\\\)\"]*)").Groups[1].Value
```

Or

```
 Regex.Match(text, "\"html\":\"((?<!\\\\$)[^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value
```

But its not working at all. Can I get this value using C# regex ?

Comment: Why not use `JavaScriptSerializer`? Why regexp?

Comment: @Amadan Because I am learning Regex lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: lookahead and lookbehind are called called zero length assertions. This means they return whether a match was found but not what it matched. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @MikeCheel Exactly! I want to make sure that [^"]* not ends with a "\" character

Answer (score 4):

There is a completely perfect for you [tool](http://json.codeplex.com/) which is **exactly** what you need in this case of parsing JSON objects.

Alright, in case you are learning Regex, here is your example of retrieving JSON data:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // {"html":"\n\t\t\t\t<table class=\"table\">"} 
        var s = "{\"html\":\"\n\t\t\t\t<table class=\\\"table\\\">\"}";
        Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\"", ParseJson("html", s).First());
        // You might wanna do Trim() on the string because of those \t\t\t etc.
    }
    static private IEnumerable<string> ParseJson(string key, string input)
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\{\""" + key + "\""\:\""(.*?)(?<!\\)\""\}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        return r.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().Select(T => T.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```

A few notes:

1. Use `(?<!\\)` as a negative lookbehind (from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) for the doublequotes not preceded by a backslash.
2. Use `RegexOptions.Singleline` for the dot (`.`) character to match the newline chars (\r & \n).
3. [Do not parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/558018) :)

Comment: He is trying to learn regex though not necessarily parse JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
/"html":"(?:[^"]*(\\"[^"]*(?<!\\)))*"/

        -                              opening quote
            -----    -----         -     then any number of non-quotes
                 ----              -     ... separated by an escaped quote
                          -------        ... where the non-quote string doesn't
                                              end in a backslash
                                    -    closing quote
```

should be a good-enough approximation for this case.

(I've written it in the standard regexp way; remember to escape backslashes and quotes for the C# string literal.)

Comment: Actually my json value is very big. And this code is not working there. I just posted here the beginning of the json.

Comment: As I said, works for this case. I can imagine it wouldn't work if you had an escaped backslash before an unescaped quote, for example, or non-string values, or values whose keys aren't `"html"`. Which is why, for real data, you use a parser with more state than regular automaton, and preferably something already written and tested (like `JavaScriptSerializer`). Or at least use a language with a powerful "regex", like [Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=995856), which implements recursion, and is thus not "regular" any more.